# How to set href in Django template page

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I'm fairly new to Django. I have homepage template that looks like this:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for link in embededLinks %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
            <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Do you get the impression that the Supreme Court doesn’t like me?</p>
            &mdash; Donald J. Trump (@realDonaldTrump) 
            <a href="{{%link%}}">June 18, 2020</a>
        </blockquote> 
        <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The loop runs through a list of links for my website to display embedded tweets correctly. This html will be put in a base template I have. Only problem is I get an error at this line:

```
<a href="{{%link%}}">June 18, 2020</a>
```

The href link is generated in another python file and is of type str. Only thing is I'm not sure how to set the href using Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not experienced in Django but I am with Flask.

Could it be that displaying a variable would be `{{ link }}` instead of `{{%link%}}`?

Answer (score 0):

In Django you can add links like href= "{% url 'url_name' %}".
Remember you have to give a name to a url/path to use it like this.
Ex:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
# let's say this index view renders home page and name is given 'index' to this urls(this name will be used for recalling urls paths and it can be anything).
]
Then your link looks like href = "{% url 'index' %}" . For more info check , 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/
```